# java: jTabbedPane tab clicked event

Tags: java, events, jtabbedpane

```
    mainPane.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            mainPaneMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });

    private void mainPaneMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    System.out.println("hahahahahahhaha");
}
```

The code above triggers when I click anywhere in the panel, not just the tab.
How do I change it to just fire when the tab is clicked
Also, will I be overriding anything JTabbedPane is doing when a tab is clicked?

Comment: Why do you want to know when the tab is clicked?

Comment: i have a jtable in the first tab, when another tab is clicked i want to move that table to the tab they clicked

Comment: Could you just link the table's model's instead?

Comment: not sure what that means but i'll look into it. thanks!

Comment: Instead of "moving" the `JTable` from one tab to another, create two `JTable`s that use the same `TableModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You Could...

Use a `ChangeListener` to detect when the tab selection changes and use something like `getSelectedIndex` to determine which tab has been selected

### You Could...

Instead of moving the `JTable` from one tab to another, create an instance of a `JTable` for each tab and share the `TableModel` between them

Comment: ok i did my research! it worked perfectly! the second suggestion that is. thanks again!